# With Ivy, how do I get the licenses of all of my project's dependencies?

Tags: ivy

Manually going through all of my project's dependencies then searching for their licenses would take a large amount of time.  Is it possible to obtain all of my dependencies' licenses and their dependencies' licenses (and so on) easily through ivy?

Answer (score 0):

The ivy [report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) task will report the licence that is listed in a module's POM file. Problem is licence information is optional and may not always be available.

```
<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>
</target>
```

Comment: This works and I also know how to make it work through Maven.  When I use Maven, dependency licenses are returned even if the license does not appear in the pom.xml file, but ivy does not return the license if the license is not in the pom.xml file.  Why is this?  I can't figure out how to get all of the dependency licenses to be returned with Maven or Ivy.

Comment: @B.Miller Licences can only be returned if it's available from the repository metadata (pom.xml or ivy.xml files). I'd be interested in an example where a license is found when non exists in the POM, I'd guess it does exist, perhaps in a parent POM?